# Unable to launch Firefox driver using selenium

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, firefoxdriver, exception

### [image]

[image]

I'm getting error like `Exception in thread main java. NoClassDefFoundError:com/google/common/collect/immutableMap`

and above are the full screen shots:

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell it where the FirefoxDriver exe is located.

e.g.

```java
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", locationFirefoxDriver);
```

Comment: I have provided the Firefox driver exe location, eventhough iam getting the same error

Note :-
#  I have using  Firefox 68.0.2 (32-bit) Fire fox Quantum
# download the geckodriver-v0.24.0-win64
.# Added gecgo driver path in the environment variable (see the below screenshot)

Comment: Comments there is image upload option.. So I will update screen shot... My previous question itself..

Comment: I have uploaded my updated  screen shot in my previous question itself..

Comment: In that case it sounds like the classpath is missing a dependency. Are you running using the selenium-server-standalone.jar? If so is the path to Java / etc definitely correct in the classpath? Or is this Maven?